# First-answer guidelines message “Avoid asking for clarification to answers” is confusing

Tags: discussion, support, answers, guidelines

When a user posts his first answer, some brief guidelines are displayed:

[image: “Avoid asking for clarification to answers”]

The message *Avoid asking for clarification to answers* confused a user on Mathematics, who [inquired about it on Mathematics Meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4845/avoid-asking-for-clarification-to-answers-what-does-it-mean). That question has 10 upvotes, suggesting people agree it's confusing.

The user interpreted it as meaning that asking for clarification etc. are not allowed at all on Stack Exchange:

> Really?? Seems draconian to me, unless i miss something. What if the answer isn't clear?

mixedmath clarified that it was intended to only discourage doing so *in answers*:

> When the guidelines suggest avoiding asking for clarification or responding to other answers, they don't mean to *avoid asking for clarification at all costs*. Instead, they mean don't ask for clarification *in your answer*. [...] So to end, one can ask for clarification on answers, but this should be done in *comments* as opposed to *other answers*.

The message should therefore be clarified.

Comment: It isn't already clear that this only applies to "Your Answer?"  I think this user just got momentarily confused.  My perpetual state of mind when reading any SO question for the first time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The flow is not natural. We have to keep reminding ourselves that the paragraph below is describing "Your answer".

Comment: Keep in mind this isn't supposed to be an entire "how to answer" guide.  It's just a few common issues with a link to the actual "how to answer" guide, which does explain that such activities belong in comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reasoning why this happens is that the comments are not allowed for zero reputationers. The next obvious thing they then try is to answer the question with a question. And that is not the meaning of an answer.

Problem would be solved if everyone could comment but I think we don't want that, because that gives a risk of lot's of bot comments filling the site.

Comment: Bot problem is better handled about questions - no-one can revise all commenting because they already are more wild than answers by nature.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's clear that text is referring to the answers, as:

- The first line says, "Your answer"
- The next line says, "Thanks for contributing an answer on [site name]."
- The line next to that says, "Please be sure to answer the question."
- The last lines says, "To learn more, see our tips on writing great answers."

The topic for that text is *answers*, and I don't see any topic change during that text. *Question* is used just once, in *to answer the question*, but the topic doesn't change from *answers* to *questions*.

I would avoid writing "Please be sure to answer the question." as it would be an item of a list, but that doesn't change the meaning of that text.